# Android XML ImageView below TextView but needs to align bottom with textView

Tags: android, xml, layout

So My text View has to be drawn over the image view, so its defined in xml like this:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chatBalloon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chatItemProfPic"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/chat_bar_user" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chatItemProfPic"
        android:text="username"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
```

but i because the textView can contain multiline text, i need to have the imageView increase its height accordingly. It would be accomplished by adding this rule:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="idOfText"
```

but because the textView hasnt been defined at that part, the app crashes. I get the same when trying to do it from code by addRule in the LayoutParams because i call it in onCreate, before the view has been drawn.

Any ideas how to bypass this?

SOLVED:
Final xml:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chatBalloon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chatItemProfPic"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/userText"
        android:src="@drawable/chat_bar_user" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/userText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chatItemProfPic"
        android:text="username"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Comment: post your log please,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use

```
 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/idOfText"
```

when you first make a reference to a particular id. Note the "+" which is adding the id to the list of resource identifiers.

Then, you can assign an existing id to a widget without using the "+", as follows:

```
android:id="@id/idOfText"
```

after. It's typical to create the id when we're assigning it, which is why you only really need to care about the presence of the "+" in relative layouts.

In your specific case:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/chatBalloon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chatItemProfPic"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/userText"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/chat_bar_user" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/userText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chatItemProfPic"
    android:text="username"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

You should have set the ID of the profile pic widget using: `android:id = "@+id/chatItemProfPic"` assuming that you are declaring the widget before any references to it. Otherwise, similarly, use "+" for the first reference, and then assign the ID when you declare the widget without the "+".

Comment: yea.. solved it like this. Wasnt aware that i could add id's from there. Thanks!

Comment: ah note, with "chatItemProfPic" you're adding the IDs each time you reference them. I would have expected it to crash there too... but typically you should only have the "+" once per ID in a layout (I think more specifically you are only allowed duplicate IDs if they are in a separate view tree). I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

why dont put that image like textview background.?

or something like:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Rlayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/img" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="lorem ipsum"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimension" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

in relative layout you could easily put text right over imageview